# Short story with little girl and artificial teacher

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The short story had a little girl named Margie who lived in the future where there were no schools and there were only artificial teaching computer systems. The girl's "teacher" was due to some reason not working and giving her hard homework. They later had to call a mechanic. The girl had a friend who had found a real book and was showing it to Margie.

I read this story somewhere in the last two years so it must be fairly new.  The short story was no longer than 2-3 pages.

Comment: You read it "somewhere?"  No idea if it was online or an actual book or magazine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Fun They Had](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fun_They_Had) by Isaac Asimov.

Like all the well known Asimov stories [this has been asked about many times](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D%20-%5Bmanga%5D%20-%5Bmovie%5D%20-%5Btv%5D%20-%5Banime%5D%20-%5Bcartoon%5D%20%22the%20fun%20they%20had%22). The girl's friend is Tommy, and he is the one who finds the real book. Margie's teacher has been setting her work that is too advanced, and a mechanic is called to reset it.

Comment: pretty sure thats it, I kept googling "short story with girl called maggie " should have used margie, and on further investigation into my earlier textbooks I found it, I read  it in 9th grade

Comment: What the heck.  Is going on.  With that plot summary.